# Mobile Number Validation In LWUIT

Tags: java, validation, java-me, lwuit, lwuit-textfield

I want to check the 10 digit phone number whether all 10 digits are same or different. If same means Invalid mobile number alert will be displayed. I want a code in LWUIT.

Answer (score 5):

set the `TextField` max size to 10. It allows only 10 digits. Also set the numeric constraint to that `TextField`. It allows only numeric value. See the sample code,

```
TextField txtf = new TextField();
txtf.setConstraint(TextField.NUMERIC);
txtf.setInputModeOrder(new String[] {"123"});
txtf.setMaxSize(10);
form.addComponent(txtf);
```

Also check the length of the text in `TextField`. If length isn't 10 digit, you can showing the alert.

For checking repeated numbers, Use [`addDataChangeListener`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/TextField.html#addDataChangeListener%28com.sun.lwuit.events.DataChangedListener%29). You can handle the validation  inside of this listener.

Comment: good answer but you should not help question like "i want code"

Comment: @ frayab, He wants to write an own logic on `addDataChangeListener`. Then only he knows about how to write and how to handle the code. right?

Comment: I'll add that there is also a phone number constraint that should work for native editing. This is very valuable in Codename One where the iOS/Android ports actually provide a different keyboard for phone number input.