# how to make textfield to accept only alphabets in LWUIT?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I have created some `TextFields`. Now I have to set constraint to that `TextField` only alphabets..I don't know how to do that in LWUIT

Comment: What have you tried since you asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156737/mobile-number-validation-in-lwuit) previously?

Comment: @radimpe , previously i tried this only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `validChar` method, try

```
TextField textField = new TextField(){
        public boolean validChar(String c) {
            if (((c.charAt(0) > 'a') && (c.charAt(0) < 'z')) || ((c.charAt(0) > 'A') && (c.charAt(0) < 'Z'))) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score -2):

You must do it by hand.
Get the first char and check it against all other until you find a different char.
Or
You can create a regexp out of the first char and match your value against it.

edit : The question has completely changed. This answer was meant for another question. So is the next answer.

Answer (score -3):

use REGEX function for that.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/javascript/3/10015479/only-allow-numeric-value-in-textbox-and-not-allowed-any-other-charcter--please-guide-how-can-i-.aspx